# How to track Account Description field changes in Field history Tracking?

Tags: apex, fields, history-tracking, field-history, accounthistory

I'm trying to track history of Account Description field.

[image]

Related list just shows it has changed, but seems no value changes being tracked. Tried to [query using SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_entityhistory.htm), but it doesn't give any value changes.

[image]

Are we supposed to have our own approach to track long text fields? (e.g. have custom object and append records upon saving usign trigger). What is a recommended approach to do this? or anything I'm missing on this.

Appreciate any thoughts. 
Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Track Changes" fields (basically, anything that's a LTA) is a limitation of the platform; it can only track changes for fields of 255 characters or less. In the UI, the changes would be listed as "Field was changed." rather than having specific from/to values. If you want to track the full values, you would indeed need a trigger/process builder to track the full values. Note that this is going to be relative cost-ineffective, as each custom object record needs 2KB of storage.

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox